# Does Collections.sort() with custom comparator does compare(a,b) and compare(b,a) for every pair (a,b)

Tags: java, collections, comparator

While using Collections.sort() with a custom comparator, I was getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

After googling about this error, I see several explanations that said if comapare(a,b) gives me -1 and compare(b,a) also gives me -1 then I will see this error.

I don't understand why is compare happening twice?

Comment: Just fix your comparator. Figuring out the exact sequence of `compare` calls the sort routine makes isn't going to help you; the sort is free to make whatever comparisons it wants as long as the output comes out sorted, and different Java versions and implementations do different things.

Comment: I understand that my comparator had issues. I'm just trying to understand if compare happens more than once for every pair

Comment: It can't happen for every pair; that'd be O(n^2) comparisons and Collections.sort is O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

[JavaDoc of Comparable's `compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

> The implementor must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y. (This implies that x.compareTo(y) must throw an exception iff y.compareTo(x) throws an exception.)
>
> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.
>
> Finally, the implementor must ensure that x.compareTo(y)==0 implies that sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z)), for all z.

In simple words, it means the following:

- If `x.compareTo(y)` throws an exception, `y.compareTo(x)` should also throw an exception.
- If `x > y`, and `y > z`, then `x > z`
- If `x.compareTo(y) == 0`, then `x.compareTo(z)` and `y.compareTo(z)` should have the same sign.

In short: If `a == b`, then `b == a`. If not, you're violating the contract.

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 1.8, `Collections.sort(..)` hands the work off to `List#sort()`, which hands the work off to `Arrays.sort(..)`, which hands the work off to class `TimSort`. [Here's a link to the API and code used for that algorithm.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TimSort.java#TimSort.sort%28java.lang.Comparable%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.Comparator%2Cjava.lang.Comparable%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29)

It's quite messy and complicated (for good reason - optimizing sorting algorithms is important), but suffice it to say that it never guarantees (or even suggests) that every pair of elements is only compared once. It guarantees at most O(n*logn) compares, but not that they will be unique comparisons.